# Drawing a XAML map in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, dwg

I'm working on a module that displays DWG files in WPF. I've managed to use CadLib library but it's working very slowly and I want to make it faster. I found out that if I convert that DWG file to SVG format and then print it to my XPS printer and rename the file to ZIP, I can get .page file which is basically a XAML file that displays the original SVG object in XAML.

I want to display this XAML code on a custom control and be able to pan / zoom it around. I tried to place this XAML code in a Canvas and it did manage to show up there, but now I'm stuck trying to pan / zoom the shape that was drawn there. Also, the mouse events are fired only when you click the actual drawing itself, and not the Canvas, which will be hard for the user to click...

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating nested Canvases : One that holds the vectors and is moved on demand, one that is fixed and serves as the viewport. Haven't tried that, but it should be feasible...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've managed to add this into another canvas object and it seems to work now. I also added zooming and panning capabilities to my control.